# What is causing the systemd error: "Timer unit lacks value setting" (no other error messages?)

Tags: systemd

I have the following timer unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for Hive management command: process_payments

[Timer]
Unit=hive-manage@process_payments.service
OnCalendar=*:0/20

[Install]
WantedBy=hive.target
```

When I check the timer status using `systemctl status hive-manage@process-payments.timer`, I see the following error in the logs:

```
● hive-manage@process-payments.timer - Timer for Hive management command: process-payments
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 02 21:28:39 boldidea systemd[1]: hive-manage@process-payments.timer: Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing.
Mar 02 21:39:06 boldidea systemd[1]: hive-manage@process-payments.timer: Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing.
Mar 02 21:39:27 boldidea systemd[1]: hive-manage@process-payments.timer: Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing.
```

After some searching, most people get an accompanying message that gives more detail on the error, however I am not getting any context other than "Timer unit lacks value setting".

This error is not very helpful -- I'm unaware of any setting named "value".

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an older unit called `process-payments`, and it was later renamed to `process_payments` (underscore instead of hyphen). I was referencing the old name in my `systemctl status` command.